# Assembly.GetExportedTypes throws exception method does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am implementing interface which have following definition

```
public interface Math
{

 int Calculate(int a, int b)
}

public class MathImpl : Math
{
  public int Calculate(int a, int b){ return a + b; }
}
```

this is code is part of assembly, which build properly

When I call `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` it throws exception method does not have an implementation.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

if I change method implementation to

```
int Math.Calculate( int a, int b){ return a + b; }
```

It works fine.

What could be reason it throws error in first case?

Comment: Try to show the code where you use Assembly.GetExportedTypes()

Comment: @Francesco:  added code to GetExportedTypes()

Comment: OK, and just this gives you the exception?

Comment: yes. If I implement interface explicitly, it works fine.

Comment: Could you post the full exception, including its stack trace?

Comment: The example code you describe above works for me. I suppose there must be some other additional condition that causes this excepetion.  We have the same problem in one of our projects. We get the same excpetion and as soon as we implement the interface explicitly the exception goes away. It would be really interesting to understand why this happens!

Answer (score 0):

From [GetExportedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes.aspx)'s help:

> Gets the **public** types defined in this assembly that are visible outside the assembly.

Neither your interface(which causes the problem here) nor your class is public.

Comment: sorry, my mistake both are public. I Will modify question. Still it throws error.

Comment: did you make them public just now?:) if yes, or any time later - I would ask where do you load the assembly from? are you sure it's the right version but not an earlier or GAC one? show some code how you get the filePath.

Comment: It is public in my working code. When I type question I just created Math interface and forgot add public :)       File path is always "C:\code" where assebly is located. Version of assembly is correct. I have checked that

Comment: question is why it works fine when implement interface explicitly?

Comment: it's really strange if that's all of your code - it somehow cannot map the method of your class to the interface method.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces has default access specifier as Public, but your class is defaulted to internal. So When you say

```
int Math.Calculate( int a, int b){ return a + b; }
```

it is working since you have interface public. It won't work if you implement it for your class which is internal.

Comment: my mistake. both are public. I have modified question. Still it throws error. If I implement interface explicitly, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what is happening, but I'm pretty sure that the problem has to do with [load contexts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx).

Comment: I read article on load context.There is till no clue why it is working for explicite implemetation and not for implecite